# How to change Doctype and Content-Type of a Meteor-App

Tags: meteor

I need to change the doctype and the content-type of a meteor-app to get CE-HTML-related things working.

Meteor works fine on CE-HTML-devices like Set-Top-Boxes. But without setting the correct doctype and content-type of the main request, some CE-HTML-based extensions won't work properly.

Thx,
Joerg

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean you want to add these to the top of your app.html:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "ce-html-1.0-transitional.dtd">
```

What you want to do is find 
  `~/.meteor/tools/latest/tools/app.html.in`
and edit it to add your doctype and content-type.

***Note:** this is a hack.* It will change the doctype and content type for all of your Meteor apps. Whenever you launch your Meteor app or bundle it, this template is used.